# how to use JQuery ReplaceWith with materials.io icons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

want the favorite_border icon to switch to favorite icon onclick.

since we use material.io and the class is material-icons for both icons, not sure how to use the jquery.
what should i do? (so we could keep use these icons)

thank you

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="leftSidebarList mdl-list">
    <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--three-line">
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
          <a class="likeUnlike" href="#">

          <i onclick="favOnclick(this)" id="likeUnpressed" class="material-icons">favorite_border</i>
          <i onclick="favOnclick(this)" id="likePressed" style="visibility:hidden" class="material-icons">favorite</i>

      </a>
    </span>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    function favOnclick(x) {
        if (document.getElementById(x) === "favorite_border") {
            x.replaceWith("favorite")
        } else {
            x.replaceWith("favorite_border")
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
    function favOnclick(x) {
        if (x.innerHTML === "favorite_border") {
            x.innerHTML = "favorite";
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "favorite_border";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You‘re welcome. Please accept the answer so that people know the problem is solved.

Comment: i'm sorry, currently i have less than 15 recorded reputations , so even though i pressed it it does not change the publicly displayed post score:(

Comment: Okay, no worries :)

Comment: @learningtocode - you need 15 reputation points to _vote_ but you do not need any points to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answers. Just **click on the checkmark** next to the answer. You even get 2 points for accepting an answer. Accepting answers is completely optional but [highly recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).